# Spark job out of RAM (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError), even though there's plenty. xmx too low?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with my Spark job, even though only 20% of the total memory is in use.

I've tried several configurations:

- 1x n1-highmem-16 + 2x n1-highmem-8
- 3x n1-highmem-8

My dataset consist of 1.8M records, read from a local json file on the master node. The entire dataset in json format is 7GB. The job I'm trying to execute involves a simple computation followed by a reduceByKey. Nothing extraordinary. The job runs fine on my single home computer with only 32GB ram (xmx28g), although it requires some caching to disk.

The job is submitted through spark-submit, locally on the server (SSH).

Stack trace and Spark config can be viewed here: https://pastee.org/sgda

**The code**

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Json.load()) // load everything
  .map(fooTransform)                  // apply some trivial transformation
  .flatMap(_.bar.toSeq)               // flatten results
  .map(c => (c, 1))                   // count 
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .sortBy(_._2)
log.v(rdd.collect.map(toString).mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: Could you please show how you distribute the RDD-s among the nodes?

Comment: It's my first time working with more than just a single node. I've added a snippet of the relevant Spark code. Do I need to manually partition it? Sorry if I misunderstood your question. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you should try to offload more I/O to the distributed tasks instead of shipping it back and forth between the driver program and the worker tasks. While it may not be obvious at times which calls are driver-local and which ones describe a distributed action, rules of thumb include avoiding `parallelize` and `collect` unless you absolutely need all of the data in one place. The amounts of data you can `Json.load()` and the `parallelize` will max out at whatever largest machine type is possible, whereas using calls like `sc.textFile` theoretically scale to hundreds of TBs or even PBs without problem.

The short-term fix in your case would be to try passing `spark-submit --conf spark.driver.memory=40g ...` or something in that range. Dataproc defaults allocate less than a quarter of the machine to driver memory because commonly the cluster must support running multiple concurrent jobs, and also needs to leave enough memory on the master node for the HDFS namenode and the YARN resource manager.

Longer term you might want to experiment with how you can load the JSON data as an RDD directly, instead of loading it in a single driver and using `parallelize` to distribute it, since this way you can dramatically speed up the input reading time by having tasks load the data in parallel (and also getting rid of the warning `Stage 0 contains a task of very large size` which is likely related to the shipping of large data from your driver to worker tasks).

Similarly, instead of `collect` and then finishing things up on the driver program, you can do things like `sc.saveAsTextFile` to save in a distributed manner, without ever bottlenecking through a single place.

Reading the input as `sc.textFile` would assume line-separated JSON, and you can parse inside some `map` task, or you can try using  [sqlContext.read.json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes). For debugging purposes, it's often enough instead of using `collect()` to just call `take(10)` to take a peek at some records without shipping all of it to the driver.

Comment: Oh man, you make a ton of sense. Turns out I didn't really understand the difference between sc.textFile and parallallize. I thought both worked in a sc.textFile-kind of manner -- but yeah, I realize I'm a moron. Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, it's so fast now! Haha. Wow. Thanks again! You made my day.

Comment: Glad it worked out! The subtleties of these distributed frameworks can certainly take some getting used to :) If you haven't already, you might also want to try loading your data from Google Cloud Storage (GCS); on Dataproc, you can use any `gs://` paths with `sc.textFile`, and that way you can get distributed access from multiple nodes or even multiple clusters without lots of copying to/from "local" filesystems. You'll just want to make sure you create your GCS bucket in the same region as your VMs to avoid cross-continent latency/costs.

Comment: Yeah, I did in fact try exactly that earlier, but I found the performance to be very bad compared to just scp-ing everything to all of the nodes before execution. My dataset is static and constant, so this seems to be the fastest. But yeah, I find Spark very hard to debug, and there's not much free support for it other than SO. Your help is really appreciated!